# How to change button text in angular 1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a list in my demo.In each item, there is drop down.I want to change the button text if the user changes any of the dropdown value.

Example:
Currently, button text is `Fixed`. If the user changes any of dropdown value (a to b or c) it should `change` the button text as well.

Here is my code:

<kbd>**`Plunk DEMO`**</kbd>

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button>{{btn}}</button>
    <div ng-repeat="x in arr">{{x}}
    <select class="selectpicker">
          <option>A</option>
          <option>B</option>
          <option>C</option>
    </select>

    </div>
  </body>
```

In other words
 I will  explain again .when you run application, if show button text is 'Fixed'. Now If I change the dropdown value `A` to `B` .First and third dropdown value  remain same `A` .Then button text is changed to `Changed`.

Comment: try ng-change on select box.

Comment: The [select directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) is used together with [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to provide data-binding between the `scope` and the `<select>` control (including setting default values). It also handles dynamic `<option>` elements, which can be added using the [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) or [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directives.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking to do validation. You can check the drop-down elements for a changed state, and modify the text on the button accordingly.

Great tutorial on Angularjs validations:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

You can set name properties on the drop-downs, and use as follows:

```
<form name="form">
   <button>{{ form.dropdown.$touched ? 'changed' : btn }}</button>
   <select name="dropdown">
      ...
   </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular inbuilt directive `ng-change`, which is fired when the value is changed

In your HTML,

```
<select class="selectpicker" ng-model="val" ng-change="update()">
```

In Your controller,

```
  $scope.update=function(){
     $scope.btn = 'Changed';
  }
```

Check the updated plunk 


<kbd>**`Plunk DEMO`**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive together with the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button>{{btn}}</button>
    <div ng-repeat="x in arr">{{x}}
        <select class="selectpicker"
                ng-model="arr.select[$index]"
                ng-change="selectAction($index)"
        >
              <option>A</option>
              <option>B</option>
              <option>C</option>
        </select>   
    </div>
</body>
```

From the Docs:

> The [select directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) is used together with [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to provide data-binding between the `scope` and the `<select>` control (including setting default values). It also handles dynamic `<option>` elements, which can be added using the [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) or [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directives.
>
> [— AngularJS `<select>` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)